# Why does my Cisco 4507 core switch not recognize my SFP+?

Tags: cisco, fiber, sfp

I have a SFP+ cable of dubious parentage (I think it is a knockoff) that I'm trying to use to connect a Cisco 2960S stack with a 4507 core chassis.  I have included what I think is relevant information below but please feel free to request more and I'll provide it.  Neither side complains about it being an incompatible SFP module, or anything of the like.  If I hook the cable up between two 2960S's, it works just fine.  The SFP cable doesn't appear to be listed on Amazon anymore, but here is a comparable version to give you an idea of what I'm using: [Diablo 15m direct attach SFP+](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KMR8R8S)

My 4507 shows "inactive" status and the 2960S's show "notconnect" leading me to believe the problem may be with the 4507.  I've attempted the `service unsupported-transceiver` trick but it has not affected the 'inactive' status.

Here is the 4507 side:

```
nyhq-core01#sh int status | inc SR
Te3/3                        inactive     1            full   auto 10GBase-SR


interface TenGigabitEthernet3/3
 switchport mode trunk
end

TenGigabitEthernet3/3 is down, line protocol is down (inactive)
  Hardware is Ten Gigabit Ethernet Port, address is e02f.6da5.8dc2 (bia e02f.6d)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 10000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, Auto-speed, link type is auto, media type is 10GBase-SR
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is off
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/2000/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 10000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, Auto-speed, link type is auto, media type is 10GBase-SR
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is off
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/2000/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 0 broadcasts (0 multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 3 interface resets
     0 unknown protocol drops
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out

NAME: "TenGigabitEthernet3/3", DESCR: "SFP-10Gbase-SR"
PID: SFP-10G-SR        , VID: V03  , SN: C1402250129
NAME: "Supervisor(slot 4)", DESCR: "Sup 7-E 10GE (SFP+), 1000BaseX (SFP) with 4 SFP+ Ports"
PID: WS-X45-SUP7-E     , VID: V04  , SN: CAT164ZZZZ
```

And here is the 2960S stack:

```
NYC-SW-26-01#sh int status | inc SR
Te2/0/1                      notconnect   1            full    10G SFP-10GBase-SR


interface TenGigabitEthernet2/0/1
 switchport mode trunk
end
TenGigabitEthernet2/0/1 is down, line protocol is down (notconnect) 
  Hardware is Ten Gigabit Ethernet, address is 44ad.d975.51b3 (bia 44ad.d975.51b3)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 10000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec, 
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive not set
  Full-duplex, 10Gb/s, link type is auto, media type is SFP-10GBase-SR
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is unsupported 
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 0 broadcasts (0 multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 0 multicast, 0 pause input
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 3 interface resets
     0 unknown protocol drops
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 pause output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out

NYC-SW-26-01#sh log | inc 2/0/1  
Jul 31 19:00:28.175: %LINK-5-CHANGED: Interface TenGigabitEthernet2/0/1, changed state to administratively down
Jul 31 19:02:17.989: %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface TenGigabitEthernet2/0/1, changed state to down

NYC-SW-26-01#sh inv
NAME: "1", DESCR: "WS-C2960S-48LPD-L"
PID: WS-C2960S-48LPD-L , VID: V04  , SN: FOC1713ZZZZ

NAME: "2", DESCR: "WS-C2960S-48LPD-L"
PID: WS-C2960S-48LPD-L , VID: V04  , SN: FOC1713ZZZZ

NAME: "TenGigabitEthernet2/0/1", DESCR: "SFP-10GBase-SR"
PID: SFP-10G-SR          , VID: V03  , SN: C1402250130     

NAME: "3", DESCR: "WS-C2960S-48LPD-L"
PID: WS-C2960S-48LPD-L , VID: V04  , SN: FOC1709ZZZZ

nyhq-core01#sh log | inc 3/3
nyhq-core01#
```

Comment: bad cable, bad SFP, or incompatible SFP. The 4507 is "inactive" which suggests it doesn't like your SFP module (i.e. non-cisco?)

Comment: The inactive status suggests missing VLANs.  Can you post show vlan?

Comment: @MikePennington I tried `service unsupported-transceiver` already as well as `no errdisable detect cause gbic-invalid` before posting this question.  Sadly, no change.

Comment: Ok... fyi there's no guarantee that 3rd party pluggable xcvrs will work in a given cisco box.  SFP is actually trickier than the old GBICs were.  To the question of isolating to either fiber or xcvr, if a known-good short fiber loop doesn't bring the xcvr up, then there's a good chance that is part of the problem

Comment: @MikePennington et al:  I tried this cable between two 2960S's and it worked without an issue, so I think my problem may be on the 4507 side.

Comment: Check your VLANs.  The show interface status shows that it recognizes the SFP, but you're missing VLANs, hence the inactive status.

Comment: @Ron My VLAN database is the same on both units.  On the 4507, we have other ten gig sfp links that work with only `switchport mode trunk` -- are you suggesting I configure allowed vlans on the interfaces on both sides and see if that affects anything?

Comment: @ron: line protocol down means vlans are irrelevant at this point.

Comment: @PeterGrace, at this point, I would lean toward agreeing with Mike (as I often do).  On the Sup 7-E's I have access to, the only inactive 10G ports are ones without transceivers.

Comment: @MikePennington so apparently, you cannot use more than two sfp+ ports on the supervisor cards?  One of my coworkers mentioned that this was the case.  We unplugged one of the standby uplinks and confirmed it came up fine.  Is there a reason why this would be the case?

Comment: @petergrace your coworker is correct and I forgot about that "feature"... if you have redundant Sup7E in the box, the switch won't allow more than 4x10GE between the two supervisors... basically port group 2 on each sup (Te3/3 and Te3/4 in your case) get disabled ([CCO ref](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11370431/redundant-supervisor-7-e-use-all-uplink-ports-same-time)).  I should see if I can convince the 4k BU folks to make it more obvious (like syslog a warning when an xcvr is inserted in a port disabled thusly).  Maybe permanently shut the port??

Comment: @PeterGrace, this has always been a limitation of the 4500 platform, even when the supervisor had two GBIC slots.  As Mike noted, when you have redundant supervisors, only the first 1 (of 2) or 2 (of 4) ports on each supervisor are usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MikePennington and YLearn have corroborated, if you have dual supervisor cards in a 4500 chassis, only the first two of the four SFP+ slots will work on each sup blade.  The other two ports are disabled in software and there is *currently* no indication to the end user that the ports are disabled.